# Crontab Job not Executing

Tags: linux, cron

System Date: 
`Wed Nov 22 02:14:54 UTC 2017`

CronJob (save environment variables to file in /tmp)

`02 12 * * * env > /tmp/env.txt`

This job did not execute between at 02:12:00 - 02:13:00 despite being initialized at 02:10:00

The command `env > /tmp/env.txt` executes just fine when I do it outside of crontab. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you start your crontab service firstly?

Comment: Nope, I'll do that! Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, still fails to execute.

```sudo service cron start```
```02 23 * * * env > /tmp/env.txt```

Comment: I figured it out. I got my hours and minutes reversed. I'm stupid. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've reversed hours and minutes in your `crontab` file.

This should fix your problem:

```
12 02 * * * env > /tmp/env.txt
```